# Transformer being shorted and opened

Tags: transformer, impedance

For a perfect transformer, 1:1 turns ratio, V1=V2, I1=I2. Z1=V1/I1. Z2=V2/I2. => Z1=Z2.

When I keep the 2nd coil open circuit, Z2 is infinite. Since Z1=Z2=infinite, if I apply perfect AC voltage zource at 1st coil, the impedance seen by the AC voltage is infinite? No current flow through 1st coil?

What if I short the 2nd coil? Z2=0=Z1, there will be infinite current flow though both coil?

I think both are wrong, but I don't know what's the problem.

Comment: Your simple model is ignoring coil resistance and core saturation.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. It feels counterintuitive, but remember: perfect transformers don't exist. Neither do perfect conductors (even superconductors have inductance) or perfect voltage sources. Ideal elements are useful models for some things, but it's important to know where the limits of the models are.